# react native build error: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is the error I got:

```js
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 191

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'XXX'.
> Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

  The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69
  Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
  line number 1
  index number 0
  Error: Attribute without valueLine: 26Column: 41Char: i    
at error (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:651:10)    
at strictFail (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:677:7)    
at SAXParser.write (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1340:13)    
at new XmlDocument (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\xmldoc\lib\xmldoc.js:261:15)
at readManifest (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\config\readManifest.js:38:10)
at Object.projectConfig (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\config\index.js:59:46)    
at Object.get project [as project] (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js:134:65)    
at D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\config\config.js:8:452
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at _objectSpread (D:\Mobile Projects\XXX\XXX\XXX\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\config\config.js:8:392)
```

Here is package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^2.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.1.5",
    "native-base": "^2.13.5",
    "patch-package": "^6.1.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "react-native-deep-linking": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-image-gallery": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-filter-picker": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-spinner-button": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.1",
    "set-cookie-parser": "^2.3.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.16",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

This project was able to be built a couple of days ago. However, without any changes, I face the aforementioned error.

I googled and found the following pages:

[react-native run-android: daemon startup failed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24733)

[can't compile and run my react native app](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25936)

I did tried both of them, but none of them worked.

Any Ideas??????

Comment: did you try deleting the signing file? `app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json`

Comment: also did you try closing the cli tool and all open files, and closing the server, then emptying the build folder. then rebuilding it?

Comment: the links I mentioned in question, suggested your solutions. I did the same, I even delete the whole build folder. Still no changes in error.

Answer (score 14):

Solution 1: Delete the android/app/build folder and try to build again. It should work

Solution 2: run `npm i --save @react-native-community/cli-platform-android`

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me, now I'm onto the next error in what I'm sure is a very long line. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the 2nd solution now I am getting this error:  Cannot run program "npx.cmd" (in directory "E:\RN\RandD\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid

Comment: Solution #2 did not work for me and #1 doesn't apply (I'm attempting to build on AppCenter). See my issue report here: jkoutavas/ReactNative-AppCenter#1

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me .

Answer (score 7):

1. First make sure your are on cmd admin
2. run `cd android && gradlew clean`
3. If it give you **error** while `gradlew clean` 
   then goto `project/android/app/build/intermediates/` and delete **signing_config folder**
4. run `gradlew clean`
5. run `react-native run-android`

Comment: On point 2. wouldn't ./gradlew clean work better?

Comment: @kierandes as for some cmd ./ does not seem to work so it's better to do cd android && gradlew clean

Answer (score 2):

Most likely some of your dependencies changed, made a big update and overrode some of your dependencies. So, do the following:

1. Remove all your ^ from the package.json. That is saying to NPM or
   YARN that is OK to update to a more updated version of your
   packages. Usually, you don't want that as this might happen.
2. Nuke your node_modules and re install everything.

Comment: This worked for me on node 14.17.0 and after Expo SDK update to 47 ! I deleted most of the rows in package.json with react-native and expo with ^ versions. Had to re-add one package, but otherwise it worked. Based on the lock file, the updates that fixed the issue were: color@3.1.2->3.1.3, css-tree@1.1.2->1.1.3, css-what@6.0.1->6.1.0, domelementtype@2.0.1->2.3.0, parse-json@5.2.0->5.0.0, prop-types@^15.6.0->15.7.2, react-native-iphone-x-helper@^1.0.3 -> 1.3.0
yaml@1.10.0->10.10.2,  and a lot of packages were removed.

Comment: This worked for me. But I had to do the ./gradlew clean command inside .<PROJECT ROOT>/android folder after second step

Answer (score 1):

Delete ./android/app/build/ folder
And try to run again. *Worked for me*

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the Node to the version 10.17.0. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error because this line was missing in manifest file

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Also had a problem inside the manifest, but another one

Comment: What issue were you having? @AntonLiannoi

Comment: Sorry @DanielDon, I don't remember exactly as it was a long time ago. I suppose it was just some typo or so

Answer (score 0):

Close your IDE,
and run the cmd as administrator to compile the project

Comment: Can you explain why that should be neccessary? According to the error message, some character could not be read - does running with elevated permissions change how this works?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with this steps:

- Remove the folder `/node_modules`
- Run `yarn install` or `npm install`
- From android studio, select `Build/Clean Project`

Answer (score 0):

After trying what they say and it didn't work, I went back to the latest version of the git, ran npm install, and it ran perfectly.