# React Native Gradle build getting failed due to react-native-pdf package

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am currenly tryign to build  React native app  on an ubuntu system . I am facing build error when I am including react-native-pdf package

The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
^. Output: info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at makeError (/home/frostdev7506/Documents/greattr/GreattrNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/frostdev7506/Documents/greattr/GreattrNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/frostdev7506/Documents/greattr/GreattrNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/home/frostdev7506/Documents/greattr/GreattrNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I tried different older versions of react-native-pdf package but having similar issue. When I remove the package and clean install node modules again , I am able to build without any issue . Even  ./gradlew clean is not working. I have tried all the solutions like

deleting android/build folder
remvoing and clean installing node modules
running gradlew -clean (not working )

I am also linking my package.json for reference

```
{
  "name": "--------",
  "version": "0.2.8",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "clean": "react-native-clean-project",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "i18next": "^22.4.6",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.4.0",
    "npm": "^9.4.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.46.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.8.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-loading-dots": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.12.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- It seems like there is an issue with a JSON string in your code. The error message indicates that the current character being read is 'i' with an int value of 105, which is the character 'i' in the string 'info'. It also mentions that the current character is not a string, number, array, or object, which suggests that there is a problem with the format of the JSON string.
- Can't build, 502 error : https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf/issues/626
- react native build error: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object : [react native build error: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744141/react-native-build-error-unable-to-determine-the-current-character-it-is-not-a)
- The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105 : https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1984
- Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object #785 : https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/785